# I am trying to BULK Insert CSV on salesforce through Walkthrough for Bulk Insert

Tags: php, salesforce

I am trying to upload a CSV file of contacts to `SALESFORCE` and am having trouble with the data in the CSV.

```
    $file_name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];

    $csv = explode("\n", file_get_contents($file_name));

    $res = array_values($csv);

    $upload_url = $instance_url . "/services/data/v44.0/jobs/ingest/$decode_res[id]/batches/";

    $curl = curl_init($upload_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $auth_header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($res));
    $curl_result = curl_exec($curl);

    print_r(json_decode($curl_result, true));
    $curl_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: it is returning this in failedresults ==>"sf__Id","sf__Created",""],"Ian,"Tom,1940-06-07Z,Birthdate,Birthdate,Chief Imagineer,Description\r",Dury,Jones,LastName,Self-described as the top branding guru on the West Coast\r",Senior Director,Title,World-renowned expert in fuzzy logic design\r",["FirstName

Answer (score 1):

```
Found the solution
The data is need to be passed in csv format
example ==>
FirstName,LastName,Title,ReportsTo.Email,Birthdate,Description
Tom,Jones,Senior Director,buyer@salesforcesample.com,1940-06-07Z,"Self-described"

    $file_name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
    $csv = explode("\n", file_get_contents($file_name));

    $res = array_values(array_filter($csv));

    $string = "";

    foreach (array_chunk($res, 1) as $value) {
        $string .= $value[0] . "\n";
    }

    $upload_url = 
    "$instance_url/services/data/v44.0/jobs/ingest/$decode_res[id]/batches/";
    $curl = curl_init($upload_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $auth_header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
    $curl_result = curl_exec($curl);
```